# "Cannot Find Symbol" error when trying to access android project resources

Tags: java, android, image, netbeans

I'm learning how to program for Android atm. Following [a tutorial for graphics](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/using-bitmap-class-object-to-draw-an-image/), I've run into a problem; Attempting to access the image I've placed in the project resources renders the error "Cannot Find Symbol". Attempting to follow the advice NetBeans provided me with, I placed the image in the same package as the file I was writing, which rendered the same error telling me that there was nothing specifically where I'd place the file.

Since a picture speaks a thousand words, here's two pictures of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Had to stitch the images together because StackOverFlow wouldn't let me post images or more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

You should make drawable folder instead of image and put image in drawable folder and acces as

```
R.drawable.your_icon_name
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem! The problem is that netbeans doesn't seem to be recognising the folder in my resources folder.

Comment: It should solve this problem, the image folder is not named correctly. Also be sure to "make" your project again, and delete any automatically added statements "import android.R;" which will make it fail.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem at one point.

To fix it I did a clean and build on the project and it gave me a new error

res\drawable\sunBLU.png Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

so I renamed my image with all lowercase letters, changed my code to match and did another clean and build.  now my program works.
Turns out it will only let you use lowercase letters in a image file name.

hope this helps other people